# Scroll to top Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been looking all over for this and the only thing that worked was to replace in CSS of the body `height: 100%` for `min-height: 100%`. The thing is that change breaks the styling of the page. Is there another workaround for this?

```
function ScrollTop() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
    return false;
}

function NextPage(page) {
    $(".page[data-page='" + page + "']").addClass("hidden");
    page = page + 1;
    $(".page[data-page='" + page + "']").removeClass("hidden");
    ScrollTop();
}
```

```css
html, body, form, #container, #mainform, #content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Just FYI this is not working in any browser (latest version of all browsers to date). Also try removing `overflow-x: hidden` from the body and still wasn't working. Also tried

```
$("#container").animate({
    scrollTop:0
}, "slow");

window.scrollTo(0, 0) //this returns undefined
```

Comment: which element has the scroll bar?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: First question resolved the problem, the bar was on a child container so i changed the selector to that child container and worked. Thanks.

Comment: Also worth noting that it looks like you're not actually bothered about the animation (the time lapse is set to 0 in your example) so you can just do `$(<target>).scrollTop(0);` instead of going through the whole `animate(blah)`; rigmarole.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working fiddle. It is working just fine.

```
$(function() {
   $('.backtotop').click(function() 
        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, .2);
        return false;
   });
});
```

This should work https://jsfiddle.net/cmhLroe1/